# разбить и соединить

Tags: php

Есть несколько строк их нужно разбить проверить и соединить

Пример

```
Характеристики|Регулирование мощности, до|100.0(%)
Характеристики|Тип котла|Пиролизный
Характеристики|Вид топлива|Твердое
```

Проблема в том что из нескольких таких строк нужно соединить в одну

Пример

```
Характеристики|Регулирование мощности, до|100.0(%):300 %:600%
Характеристики|Тип котла|Пиролизный:Буржуйский:Обычный
Характеристики|Вид топлива|Твердое:Мягкое:Твердое
```

Что и как

**Характеристики|** - всегда одинаково и присутствует в каждой строке
**Регулирование мощности, до** - Название характеристики называются одинаково но могут находится то на 5 строке, а то и на 2
**100.0(%)** - значение строки всегда разные и нужно собрать и разделить :

Каждый блок строк берем из разных массивов

```
    $one_post = $_POST['one'];
    $two_post = $_POST['two'];
и так до 10 массивов
```

Я пытаюсь реализовать так все разбиваю Название характеристики перевожу в ключ потом сравниваю ключи и собираю все значения к ключу и получаю один общий блок.

Comment: надо бы уточнить, вы хотите строку `Характеристики|Регулирование мощности, до|100.0(%)` преобразовать к виду `Характеристики|Регулирование мощности, до|100.0(%):300 %:600%` ? Если да, то откуда брать эти данные для добавления?

Comment: @Эдуард с других массивов к примеру - $one_post = $_POST['one'];
$two_post = $_POST['two'];
$three_post = $_POST['three'];
$four_post = $_POST['four']; А с первого берем перво-источник

Comment: чтоб не плодить множество уточняющих комментариев, воспользуйтесь ссылкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/792606/edit), чтобы добавить в ваш вопрос пример данных из другого массива. Чем понятнее вы опишете суть задачи, тем быстрее вам помогут в её решении.

Comment: @Эдуард обновил вроде-бы все понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Парсим один массив строк
function parseStrings(&$data, $strings) {
  // Пробегаем по всем строкам
  foreach ($strings as $str) {
    // Разбиваем строку по разделителю
    $row = explode('|', $str);
    // Первую часть отбрасываем, вторая будет ключом подмассива
    if (!isset($data[$row[1]]))  // если такого подмассива нет - создаем
      $data[$row[1]] = [];
    // добавляем значение в нужный массив характеристик
    $data[$row[1]][] = $row[2];
  }
}

$strings1 = [
  "Характеристики|Регулирование мощности, до|100.0(%)",
  "Характеристики|Тип котла|Пиролизный"
  "Характеристики|Вид топлива|Твердое"
];

$strings2 = [
  "Характеристики|Регулирование мощности, до|300.0(%)",
  "Характеристики|Тип котла|Обычный"
  "Характеристики|Вид топлива|Мягкое"
];

$data = [];
// Парсим каждый из массивов и собираем все в $data
parseStrings($data, $strings1);
parseStrings($data, $strings2);

$res = [];  // конечный массив строк
// цикл по всем характеристикам.
// $name - название, $vals - массив всех значений
foreach($data as $name => $vals) {
  // Формируем новую строку
  $res[] = 'Характеристики|' . $name . '|' . implode(':', $vals);
}
```

Comment: и первый и второй вариант рабочий и мне как тупо обработать гору текста подходят оба 
Спасибо